# How do i upload an image and return the image id?

Tags: images, uploads, attachments, media

I need to import images from an url and return the image id

is it possible to make a function like this?

```
    <?php
$link = 'https://mosaic01.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-zoom/NI/11/3D/03/4D/11/NI113D034-D11@12.jpg';
$title = 'the image title';
$alt = 'the image alt';

$image_id = insert_image($link, $title, $alt);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at side loading images. [`media_sideload_image()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image)/[`wp_handle_sideload()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload) and get the ID from the URL. [`attachment_url_to_postid`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/).

```
<?php

$url = "http://wordpress.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-stacked-rgb.png";
$title = "Some Image Title";
$alt_text = "Some Alt Text";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// sideload the image --- requires the files above to work correctly
$src = media_sideload_image( $url, null, null, 'src' );

// convert the url to image id
$image_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $src );

if( $image_id ) {

    // make sure the post exists
    $image = get_post( $image_id );

    if( $image) {

        // Add title to image
        wp_update_post( array (
            'ID'         => $image->ID,
            'post_title' => "Some Image Title",
        ) );

        // Add Alt text to image
        update_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $alt_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: this function only returns the img tag or the image source, i am trying to upload the image and get the wordpress id

Answer (score 0):

What id? The HTML ID? If not, maybe you need a regex to search the url in order to find a pattern that you can assign as id. This question are a little confusing, can you give me a plain explain about it?